# Error: Apostrophe non fermé @ 124

Tags: mysql

I have this Error:
when i do this update:
ERROR: Apostrophe non fermé @ 124
STR: '

```
update referent set genderReferent='',phoneReferent='',faxReferent='',adressReferent='38, boulevard de l'Ayrolles - B.P. 145',supportOrganization='',zipCode='',cityReferent='',countryReferent='' where oldReferentId=5077
```

> Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'Ayrolles - B.P.
>   145',supportOrganization='',zipCode='',cityReferent='',countryRe' Ã 
>   la ligne 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add additional `'` inside `''` for `adressReferent`:

```
update referent
set genderReferent='',
    phoneReferent='',
    faxReferent='',
    adressReferent='38, boulevard de l''Ayrolles - B.P. 145',
    supportOrganization='',
    zipCode='',
    cityReferent='',
    countryReferent='' 
where oldReferentId=5077
```

Comment: i get that dynamically how can i resolved that issue thanks in advance

Comment: @kurchisuiden **You should add PHP code to your question.** Anyway if it is concatenated SQL string you should use parameter binding and special characters will be espaced automatically.